# Simulating a probit model with autocorrelated error

Tags: simulation, autocorrelation, probit

I have the following probit model: 
$$
\pi_t=\gamma y_{t-1}+\alpha\cdot\pi_{t-1}+\textbf{$X'\beta$}
$$ 
with $P(Y=1)=\Phi(\pi_t)$. Now I want to simulate the model to see how it behaves when certain assumptions aren't fulfilled, but I'm not really sure if I'm doing it correctly. To model autocorrelation I just added an autocorrelated error term in the form 
$$
\pi_t=\gamma y_{t-1}+\alpha\cdot\pi_{t-1}+\textbf{$X'\beta$}+\epsilon_t
$$ 
with $\epsilon_t=\rho\epsilon_{t-1}+u_t$. From this I'm receiving some seriously biased estimators, which, according to my professor, shouldn't happen.

Since my professor tends to be cryptic in his remarks, I thought maybe you guys have an idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Shouldn't $X$ be indexed by $t$?